# automating linux GUI app with touch events

Tags: automation

I'm trying to automate performing some events in an application running under X11.  To do so, I need to send touch (*not* mouse) events to specific locations in the window.  For instance, I need to long press a certain location (e.g. touch down for 2 seconds, then touch up), then touch other locations.  There are a total of about 20 different pairs of touch down and touch up events.  I'm looking for something that uses a simple scripting language.

I looked at *AutoKey* API but it can neither send touch events (it only has mouse events) and furthermore those mouse events are limited to clicks, e.g. you can't specify down and up events separately.

I also found xdotool, and while it gives more control over separating down and up events, it only provides mouse events and not touch events.  It is critical for my application that I be able to send touch events specifically as if a touch screen was present, as there are certain aspects of functionality in the app that can only be accessed via touch events, and not the mouse.

Comment: Does your application care whether it is a touchpad or a mouse generating the click?

Comment: @vanadium i'm not sure about that part, but it does distinguish between screen touch events and mouse/touchpad events

Comment: Clarify your question in that case, specifying you are referring to screen touch events. However, even there, I would feel that also that translates to the application receiving a "click" event, independent of the source. Compare typing from different attached keyboards. The end result is letters on the screen.